# Quick question: Splitting of sheaves on the plane

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, reference-request

We work in the algebraic setting.

Let $l$ be a line on the projective plane $\mathbb{P}^2$. Let $E$ be a rank $r$ torsion free coherent sheaf on $\mathbb{P}^2$ such that $E|_l\simeq\mathcal{O}_l^{\oplus r}$.

Suppose every isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_l^{\oplus r}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_l^{\oplus r}$, which is given by a diagonal $r\times r$-matrix, can be extended to an isomorphism $E\rightarrow E$.

> Why does $E$ split into a direct sum of rank $1$ sheaves?

Can something similar be true if we replace $\mathbb{P}^2$ and $l$ by, say, a rational surface and some divisor on it?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it follows (by continuity) that every diagonalizable endomorphism also can be extended. Note also that an extension is always unique (otherwise, the difference of two extensions would give a morphism $E \to E(-1)$; this morphism is zero on $l$ hence factors through $E \to E(-2)$, e.t.c, so we get a morphism $E \to E(-k)$ for every $k$ which is clearly impossible).

Now consider endomorphisms $f_i$ which are the projectors onto the summands on $l$, and let $F_i$ be their extensions to endomorphisms of $E$. Then we have $f_if_j =\delta_{ij}f_i$ and $\sum f_i = \mathrm{id}$. By uniqueness of extension it follows that $F_iF_j = \delta_{ij}F_i$, $\sum F_i = \mathrm{id}$, hence $F_i$ form a system of orthogonal idempotents and thus induces the desired direct sum decomposition.

In the above argument the only property that was used is ampleness of $l$.
Even rationality of the surface is not important.

Comment: "the difference of two extensions would give a morphism $E \to E(-1)$; this morphism is zero on $l$ hence factors through $E \to E(-2)$" $\rightarrow$ why is the morphism still zero on $l$, you already use that fact to interpret it as a morphism from $E\to E(-1)$ instead of $E\rightarrow E$?

Comment: Because when restricted to $l$ it is a morphism $O_l^{\oplus r} \to O_l(-1)^{\oplus r}$, and every such morphism is zero.